# Sending automatic email from PostgreSQL 9.4 by scheduling jobs in pgAgent

Tags: windows, postgresql

Can you please help me in configuring automatic email in PostgrSQL 9.4 so that i can schedule this on pgAgent.

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Check this Q/A:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12002662/how-can-i-send-email-from-postgresql-trigger

Answer (score 0):

Don't! Instead, use a Windows Task Scheduler job to run a script/program that queries the database and sends emails.

Sending the emails from a procedure inside the DB is quite a backwards approach.